# Streamwriter: Polish characters are skipped?

Tags: c#, encoding, streamwriter, windows-1252

I'm trying to make a small tool to help some guys converting data between a SAP installation and a Axapta installation.

I get a text file i Western European (Windows) encoding (1252). They have put in some special chars to replace some Polish characters. Now it's my job to replace those special chars with the correct Polish characters.

```
FileStream objFile = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read);
StreamReader objTemp = new StreamReader(objFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

FileStream objFile2 = new FileStream(FilePath + "_new", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter objTemp2 = new StreamWriter(objFile2, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

while ((strLineText = objTemp.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strOuterArray.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] strInnerArray = strOuterArray[i].Split(new char[]{';'});
        strLineText = strLineText.Replace(strInnerArray[0], strInnerArray[1]);
    }

    objTemp2.WriteLine(strLineText);
}

objTemp.Close();
objTemp.Dispose();

objFile.Close();
objFile.Dispose();

objTemp2.Flush();
objTemp2.Close();
```

If I debug the application and set a breakpoint on the "objTemp2.WriteLine(strLineText);" line. Then I can se that the value inside the strLineText variable is perfect. The special char is replaced by the correct Polish character.

If I open the written file afterwards then I can't find the correct Polish characters. I'm working with "ś" & "Ś", both is just saved as "s" & "S" in the file.

Did I miss something or have I overlooked something very important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the Polish characters concerned do not exist in the windows-1252 code page.

Can you confirm whether they are on the [this grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305145.aspx)?

My suggestion would be to open the output stream (stream writer) with a UTF-8 encoding or somesuch, which will support all the characters you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply rob. No - the characters isn't listed on the page you link to. I have been telling them that I think they are using the wrong encoding but they wont listen. Now I have something to give to them and then they can see for them self.

Thank you!